# I have to make this calendar program and it isn't running

Tags: python

Here is my code that isn't running. It's a calendar program that counts days, days left in year, and leap years.

Comment: Please add your code inside your answer instead of linking an image

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I put my code in the answer

Comment: where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
def leap_year():
    if y % 400 == 0:
        return 1
    elif y % 100 == 0:
        return 0 
    elif y % 4 == 0:
        return 1 
    else:
        return 0 



def number_of_days(m, y):
    y = leap_year(y)
    if (m == 1 or m == 3 or m == 5 or m == 7 or m == 8 or m == 10 or m == 12):
        return 31 
    elif (m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 11):
        return 30
    elif (m == 2):
        if (y == 1):
            return 29 
        elif (y == 0):
            return 28 
    print(m)



def days_left(d, m, y):
    daysleft = 0
    for i in range(m,13):
        days_left += number_of_days(m, y)
    m += 1 
    print(days_left - d)


print("Please enter a date")
d = int(input("Day: "))
m = int(input("Month: "))
y = int(input("Year: ")) 
print("Menu: ")
print("1) Calculate the number of days in the given month: ")
print("2) Calculate the number of days left in the given year: ") 
menu = int(input())
if menu == 1:
    print(number_of_days(m, y))
elif menu == 2:
    print(days_left(d, m, y))
else: 
    print("Invalid choice")
```

Comment: Thanks for adding you code! Please add it by editing your original question. Adding it as an answer will make it appear as if your question has been answered and you will not receive as much help.

Answer (score 0):

The first three errors in your code are:

1. function `leap_year` is declared with `0` parameters and is called with `1`.
2. In the function `days_left` you have an assignment `daysleft = 0` and then `days_left += 1
3. Wrong indentation in the same function @ `m += 1`